# MapMyFitness i/o usage

Tags: json, web-services, api, mapmyfitness

(This post may cause me bad reputation, but anyway)

There's the portal for sport activity sharing - [MapMyFitness](http://www.mapmyfitness.com/)

And here's [their API](https://developer.mapmyapi.com/)

I want to test Post Workout in [I/O docs](https://developer.mapmyapi.com/io-docs). The fields are:

```
activity_type        /v7.0/activity_type/16/    

aggregates       test   

name         Run / Jog  

privacy      /v7.0/privacy_option/3/    

start_datetime       Sat, 14 Dec 2013 12:22:43 GMT  

start_locale_timezone   US/Central
```

But still I have the next error:

```
    "error_message": "Could not deserialize body as given content type"
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Unfortunately, I didn't find any community or active forum to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some of the information required to fully answer your question, but I have a hunch that you are requesting a content-type that is not 'application/json'.  The workout API only supports JSON responses.

If you look again at the [I/O Docs](https://www.mapmyapi.com/io-docs) for POST Workout, you'll see the Content-type field is filled in with application/json by default.